# Keeping a cumulative sum of previous year data - SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to write a query that looks at data points that include an id, date, and value. These data points represent an employee's time off.

Here is an example of some sample data points (time off requests):

```
+------------+-------+-------+-------------+
|    Date    | Value | Total |   Status    |
+------------+-------+-------+-------------+
| 8/20/2015  |  0.25 |  0.25 |             |
| 1/11/2016  |     1 |  1.25 |             |
| 5/27/2016  |   0.5 |  1.75 |             |
| 8/5/2016   |  0.25 |     2 |             |
| 9/13/2016  |     0 |  1.75 |             |
| 9/28/2016  |  0.25 |     2 |             |
| 9/29/2016  |  0.25 |  2.25 |             |
| 10/17/2016 |     0 |  2.25 |             |
| 10/17/2016 |     1 |  3.25 | Verbal      |
| 11/17/2016 |  0.25 |   3.5 |             |
| 12/1/2016  |     1 |   4.5 | Written     |
| 12/2/2016  |     1 |   5.5 | Final       |
| 12/6/2016  |  0.25 |  5.75 |             |
| 12/14/2016 |  0.25 |     6 | Termination |
| 12/19/2016 |  0.25 |  6.25 |             |
| 1/6/2017   |  0.25 |   6.5 |             |
| 2/15/2017  |  0.25 |  5.75 | Final       |
| 3/15/2017  |  0.25 |     6 | Termination |
| 4/17/2017  |  0.25 |  6.25 |             |
| 5/8/2017   |     0 |  6.25 |             |
| 5/9/2017   |     1 |  7.25 |             |
| 5/21/2017  |  0.25 |   7.5 |             |
|            |       |       |             |
+------------+-------+-------+-------------+
```

I want to have a query that calculates the above result. The total column is calculated by the sum of the previous data points within the 1 year of the current data point date. So if the current data point has a date of 9/29/2016 I would like to add up all the prior data points that are between 9/29/2015 - 9/29/2016.

My end goal with this query to see if a person has two final warnings within the last year based on their time off (data points). Based on my example that I provided there was a final warning issued on 12/2/2016 and 2/15/2017 and they occurred within the last year (8/21/2016 - 8/21/2017).

What is the best way of doing this?

Here is what I currently have:

```
SELECT 
    a.dtmDATEAPP AS [Date],
    MAX(CASE WHEN a.dtmDATEAPP = b.dtmDATEAPP THEN a.strOCCUR END) AS [Value],
    SUM(b.strOCCUR) AS Total,
    CASE 
       WHEN SUM(b.strOCCUR) >= 5 AND SUM(b.strOCCUR) < 6 
          THEN 'Final' 
    END AS [Status]
FROM 
    [Attendance].[dbo].[TIMEUSE] a
JOIN 
    [Attendance].[dbo].[TIMEUSE] b ON b.dtmDATEAPP BETWEEN DATEADD(year, -1, a.dtmDATEAPP) AND a.dtmDATEAPP
WHERE 
    a.lngEMPID = 1162002 
    AND a.Absence <> 'Scheduled' 
    AND b.lngEMPID = 1162002 
    AND b.Absence <> 'Scheduled'
GROUP BY 
    a.dtmDATEAPP
ORDER BY 
    a.dtmDATEAPP
```

I am not sure the best route to see if an employee has 2 final warnings within the last year.

All help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this might help you:

```
declare @TimeUsage table
(
missingDate date,
absence varchar(20),
pctDay decimal(6,2),
status varchar(20),
employeeid int
)
INSERT INTO @TimeUsage VALUES
('8/20/2015', 'Unscheduled', 0.25, '', 1162002),              
('1/11/2016', 'Unscheduled', 1, '', 1162002),              
('5/27/2016', 'Unscheduled', 0.5, '', 1162002),              
('8/5/2016', 'Unscheduled', 0.25, '', 1162002),              
('9/13/2016', 'Unscheduled', 0, '', 1162002),              
('9/28/2016', 'Unscheduled', 0.25, '', 1162002),              
('9/29/2016', 'Unscheduled', 0.25, '', 1162002),              
('10/17/2016', 'Unscheduled', 0, '', 1162002),              
('10/17/2016', 'Unscheduled', 1, 'Verbal', 1162002),        
('11/17/2016', 'Unscheduled', 0.25, '', 1162002),              
('12/1/2016', 'Unscheduled', 1, 'Written', 1162002),       
('12/2/2016', 'Unscheduled', 1, 'Final', 1162002),         
('12/6/2016', 'Unscheduled', 0.25, '', 1162002),              
('12/14/2016', 'Unscheduled', 0.25, 'Termination', 1162002),   
('12/19/2016', 'Unscheduled', 0.25, '', 1162002),              
('1/6/2017', 'Unscheduled', 0.25, '', 1162002),              
('2/15/2017', 'Unscheduled', 0.25, 'Final', 1162002),         
('3/15/2017', 'Unscheduled', 0.25, 'Termination', 1162002),   
('4/17/2017', 'Unscheduled', 0.25, '', 1162002),              
('5/8/2017', 'Unscheduled', 0, '', 1162002),              
('5/9/2017', 'Unscheduled', 1, '', 1162002),              
('5/21/2017', 'Unscheduled', 0.25, '', 1162002)  

;WITH cte AS
(SELECT missingDate, pctDay, 
(SELECT SUM(pctDay) FROM @TimeUsage 
WHERE missingDate <= d.missingDate 
AND missingDate >= DATEADD(yy,-1,d.missingDate) 
AND employeeid = d.employeeid
AND absence <> 'Scheduled') as prevYrTot, 
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM @TimeUsage 
WHERE missingDate <= d.missingDate 
AND missingDate >= DATEADD(yy,-1,d.missingDate) 
AND employeeid = d.employeeid
AND status = 'Final') AS FinalCount,
status,employeeid 
from @TimeUsage d)
SELECT * FROM cte where employeeid IN 
(SELECT DISTINCT(employeeid) FROM cte WHERE FinalCount > 1)
```

EDIT

If Final Status is determined by prevyrtot then try this:

```
declare @TimeUsage table
(
missingDate date,
absence varchar(20),
pctDay decimal(6,2),
employeeid int
)
INSERT INTO @TimeUsage VALUES
('8/20/2015', 'Unscheduled', 0.25, 1162002),              
('1/11/2016', 'Unscheduled', 1, 1162002),              
('5/27/2016', 'Unscheduled', 0.5, 1162002),              
('8/5/2016', 'Unscheduled', 0.25, 1162002),              
('9/13/2016', 'Unscheduled', 0, 1162002),              
('9/28/2016', 'Unscheduled', 0.25, 1162002),              
('9/29/2016', 'Unscheduled', 0.25, 1162002),              
('10/17/2016', 'Unscheduled', 0, 1162002),              
('10/17/2016', 'Unscheduled', 1, 1162002),        
('11/17/2016', 'Unscheduled', 0.25, 1162002),              
('12/1/2016', 'Unscheduled', 1, 1162002),       
('12/2/2016', 'Unscheduled', 1, 1162002),         
('12/6/2016', 'Unscheduled', 0.25, 1162002),              
('12/14/2016', 'Unscheduled', 0.25, 1162002),   
('12/19/2016', 'Unscheduled', 0.25, 1162002),              
('1/6/2017', 'Unscheduled', 0.25, 1162002),              
('2/15/2017', 'Unscheduled', 0.25, 1162002),         
('3/15/2017', 'Unscheduled', 0.25, 1162002),   
('4/17/2017', 'Unscheduled', 0.25, 1162002),              
('5/8/2017', 'Unscheduled', 0, 1162002),              
('5/9/2017', 'Unscheduled', 1, 1162002),              
('5/21/2017', 'Unscheduled', 0.25, 1162002)  

;WITH cte as
(SELECT missingDate, pctDay, prevYrTot, employeeid, 
CASE WHEN prevYrTot >= 5 AND prevYrTot < 6 
THEN 'Final' ELSE '' END AS Status FROM
(SELECT missingDate, pctDay, 
(SELECT SUM(pctDay) FROM @TimeUsage 
WHERE missingDate <= d.missingDate 
AND missingDate >= DATEADD(yy,-1,d.missingDate) 
AND employeeid = d.employeeid
AND absence <> 'Scheduled') as prevYrTot, 
employeeid 
from @TimeUsage d) tu)
SELECT missingDate, pctDay, prevYrTot, employeeid, Status FROM cte 
WHERE employeeid IN 
(SELECT DISTINCT employeeid FROM (SELECT employeeid, COUNT(*) as FinalCount FROM cte 
WHERE Status = 'Final'
GROUP BY employeeid
HAVING Count(*) > 1) de)
```

I think that does what you want, but you need to test! It works for the data given.

Comment: This really close to what I am looking for except that my table does not have a column for status. I can determine that a final if the total >= 5 and < 6. How can I add this into your query?

Comment: If status comes from another table then you need to change the SELECT COUNT(*) sub-query.  To add a criteria about total simply add at the end AND employeeid IN (SELECT DISTINCT(employeeid) FROM cte WHERE prevYrTot >= 5)

Comment: @Aaron  Please try my Edit - I think this does what you want